# Why do posts disappear from admin after upgrading from WP 2.7.1 to 3.0.1?

Tags: customization, plugins, updates

After upgrading from WP 2.7.1 to 3.0.1, many of my posts are not showing in the admin section.

I have almost 30 posts, but they're not showing on the post admin page.

I created a mirror so I have a backup. But the problem is I can't upgrade WP +all plug-ins which I'm using in 2.7.1 because many posts are not showing on testing mirror.

But they are showing on main live version.

Comment: Do the posts show on the front-end of your test site?  Or are they only missing from the admin side of things?  Did you deactivate all of your plug-ins before upgrading to 3.0.1?  Does anything change if you deactivate all plug-ins and switch to the default (TwentyTen) theme?

Comment: @EAMann - Posts not showing anywhere. Yes i deactivated all plug-ins before to upgrade Wordpress. I haven't checked with TwentyTen them. Will check it now.

Comment: @EAMann - No difference with default (TwentyTen) theme. Posts are still not showing.

Comment: It might help if we could see what's going on.  I don't know if somehow your database was corrupted or if there's something else happening because I can't see it.  I suggest contacting the Support Forums (www.wordpress.org/support) and asking someone to take a look at your site.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen a couple of times where one of the database tables count of posts differs from the actual number and all the posts disappear.

Using PHPMyAdmin and go into your WP database.  Look down your columns (I think it's the "Records" column) and see if any of them show corrupt or some other error message.  If so, check the box next to that table name, then at the bottom of the table, select "Repair Table" from the select box that says "With Selected".

If that's your problem, the above should fix it.

Comment: Where i found overhead in phpmyadmin I repaired those tables. but problem is still not solved

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar problem on Pages.

They show at the backend fine but online is just a white page.

Have determined this:

Disabling all the plugins didn't affect the problem
Changing to the default theme didn't affect the problem
Increasing php.ini memory to 128M had no affect

A typical case is a page with 3 col x 9 rows. This displays as a blank page.

If I delete a group of the three rows the page displays.

On a nother site we have a small amount of text with 2 images set right at 400px.

Below the text is a 3 col x 4 rows each containing a small 180px 72dpi image.

With 12 images in the table the page dies online but still looks fine in the backend.

With 11 images in the table the page will display.